# "find | xargs | ls" not running ls on filenames from find

Tags: shell, unix, find, xargs

So I have a directory with files and sub-directories in it. I want to get all the files recursively and then list them in long format, sorted by the modified date. Here's what I came up with.

```
find . -type f | xargs -d "\n" | ls -lt
```

However this only lists the files in the current directory and not the sub-directories. I don't understand why, given that the following prints out all the files.

```
find . -type f | xargs -d "\n" | cat
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Remove `|` between `xargs` and `ls`

Comment: By the way, note that this general approach only works to sort a list of file names short enough to fit on a single command line. Once that's no longer the case, your output will have multiple smaller, individually-sorted lists within it, but it won't be sorted as a whole.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #3](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) for guidance on how to sort files by modification time more reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs` can only start `ls` if it's passed `ls` *as an argument*. When you pipe from `xargs` into `ls`, only one copy of `ls` is started -- by the parent shell -- and it isn't given any of the filenames from `find | xargs` as arguments -- instead they're on its stdin, but *`ls` never reads its stdin*, so it doesn't even know that they're there.

Thus, you need to remove the `|` character:

```
# Does what you specified in the common case, but buggy; don't use this
# (filenames can contain newlines!)
# ...also, xargs -d is GNU-only
find . -type f | xargs -d '\n' ls -lt
```

...or, better:

```
# uses NUL separators, which cannot exist inside filenames
# also, while a non-POSIX extension, this is supported in both GNU and BSD xargs
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt
```

...or, even better than that:

```
# no need for xargs at all here; find -exec can do the same thing
# -exec ... {} + is POSIX-mandated functionality since 2008
find . -type f -exec ls -lt {} +
```

Much of the content in this answer is also covered in the *Actions*, *Complex Actions*, and *Actions in Bulk* sections of [Using Find](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind), which is well worth reading.